# how to disable insert data into DB (FR3DLdapBundle)?

Tags: symfony, fr3dldapbundle

FR3DLdapBundle will insert data into DB, if ldap authentication successes, but no data in DB exists.

How can i disable it?

I have already an user table with many usernames and roles, and i don't want to insert more data into it throw LdapBundle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from **Maks3w**
More details see here: https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/issues/19